# How to disable Windows Defender automatic updates

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-defender

Every time I resume my computer and try to use it, it seems slow to respond; high disk activity, high CPU usage and low on memory. I have confirmed that it is caused by Windows Defender automatic definitions update + quick system scan which runs immediately when I resume my computer (after 8-12 hours of hibernation). I have this problem in both of computers and both are running Windows 10 Home version 1909.

I want to be in control of my computer, not the other way round. So, how can I disable Windows Defender's automatic definitions update? I would update the definitions manually at the time of my choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Defender (now Microsoft Defender Antivirus) definition updates are provided through Windows Update now. You cannot disable them without disabling Windows Update, though these definition updates shouldn't have a serious effect on your computer. They are quite small, require minimal effort and only take around a minute to install, even on the least powerful of machines. You don't need to worry about these. These aren't the cause of your problem.

Automatic system scans cannot be disabled without disabling Microsoft Defender entirely.

The solution I'd suggest is using a different, more lightweight antivirus (such as [Bitdefender](https://www.bitdefender.com/solutions/free.html), which is free, and is the one I use myself). Installing another antivirus will automatically disable Microsoft Defender entirely, which will disable automatic scans, and hopefully solve your problem.

Comment: Does pausing Windows update help?

Comment: It will stop Defender definition updates, but then your computer will stop receiving important driver updates, Windows updates, and bug fixes. Also, Windows only allows you to pause Windows Update for up to 7 days.

Comment: I'd advise installing another, more lightweight antivirus such as [Bitdefender](https://www.bitdefender.com/solutions/free.html), the one I use myself. Doing this will disable Defender, and should solve your automatic scan problem.

Comment: I have edited my answer, please re-read it. If it helps you, click the green tick next to it to mark it as the accepted solution.

Comment: The last paragraph is the solution for me I guess.

Comment: Is there a dummy av software that effectively replaces Defender but does nothing else instead?

Comment: Just wanted to add that installing another AV did not solve all my problems. When I "pause" the other AV, Windows defender comes back to life after some time, even tried to update itself.

Answer (score -1):

Currently, it's unable to turn off Windows Defender update independently because its update has little impact on the system. If you want to turn off its automatic updates, you can only turn off Windows Defender. And if you really need this feature, I would suggest to press "Win+F" to start the Feedback Hub to raise this issue so that Microsoft engineers can investigate and deal with it.